# symfony 5 remove public from url

Tags: symfony, routes

I`d like to remove public from url in symfony5.3

1. I created project 'symfony1'   (/var/www/html/symfony1)
2. I added in the project directory a .htaccess file, with the below mentioned content:
   '''

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /symfony1/public/index.php/$1 [L]

   '''

3)after that I got such an error: No route found for "GET http://localhost/symfony1/"
4)when I rewrote config/routes.yaml as:

```
index:
   path: /symfony1/
   controller: App\Controller\GoodsController::index
```

it removes 'public' from url, but I not sure tt is the correct way to do.

Comment: Yes, public should not be in the url. What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Public is a your webserver entry point, which is you make a right configuration.

On routes.yaml
U add a path as a /symfony1/

So
Your the url u want to reach is
domain.com/symfony1